# Fire dropdown nav link on second click on tablets

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I want to fire a dropdown nav link on second click on tablets. On the iPad, it already does this. You click the a tag and the child menu div drops down.

On Android and Windows tablets, the dropdown occurs, but fires the link at the same time.

Code:

```
   jQuery("ul.menuTop > li a.students" ).mouseenter(function( event ){

        event.stopImmediatePropagation()

        jQuery("#studentsMenu" ).fadeIn();
        jQuery("#facultyMenu" ).hide();
        jQuery("#staffMenu" ).hide();
        jQuery("#alumniMenu" ).hide();
        jQuery("#aboutMenu" ).hide(); 
    });

    jQuery(".menuWrapper" ).mouseleave(function (){
        jQuery("#studentsMenu" ).hide();
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution.

```
         var isMobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/);
         var link = jQuery("ul.menuTop > li a.students")

         if (isMobile) {
             jQuery(link).one("click", function (ev) {

                 ev.preventDefault();
             });

             if (jQuery("#studentsMenu").is(":visible")) {

                 jQuery(link).click(function (ev) {

                     ev.window.location = "/students";

                 });

             }
         }
```

Doesn't seem to work on Windows Tablet IE even with "Windows" in the userAgent match. Any suggestions on that fix would be great.